# Anyone else seeing an overlapping admin/civi menu bug with Joomla 3.8.13 and CiviCRM 5.6.0?

Tags: menu, css

After an upgrade to Joomla 3.8.13 and Civi 5.6.0 the Joomla admin menu dropdown is stacking under the Civi menu. I can't reproduce on https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org as even if the versions weren't 3812 and 560, the Joomla admin menu isn't long enough.

[image: Screengrab of the Civi Admin menu overlapping the Joomla admin menu dropdown]

Comment: We have seen this, too.  https://joomla.demo.civicrm.org is at 5.5.3 with the database only partially updated, so therefore cannot be used to reproduce issues in 5.6.x.

Comment: tbf - even if the demo was on 5.6.x it wouldn't help as the menus are much shorter there. Does this fix it for you? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12947/commits/e989982293dca9efbd18cd182b507f0b2bcf444a

Comment: This is fixed in CiviCRM 5.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that restoring the z-index that was removed in root/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/joomla.css corrects this issue. The rest of the removed code makes no difference. This works for me:

```
ul#civicrm-menu {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;}
```

Answer (score 3):

There was a [commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/8aa67b8570e786f5d0348d2d1bedeeebca17fafb) that fixed css for shoreditch theme probably that might have caused the regression in Joomla. Can you try to replace the code from the [commit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/8aa67b8570e786f5d0348d2d1bedeeebca17fafb) and see if it works? If so I can file a issue and submit the patch for regression.

Comment: Thanks Pradeep (sorry for the delay in reply). Yes, as LMK suggests, restoring the z-index from that commit fixed this.

Comment: So can we mark this as answered so that it can help others who face similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I checked my joomla.css and the z-index lines are already there but i still can't see the administrator menu any more:

text-align:left;
}

/* Joomla Admin Menu alterations */
/* Moved from civicrm.css in v3.2 */

ul#civicrm-menu {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

div#toolbar-box div.m {
  padding: 0px !important;

Anything else I can try please?

Comment: Hi Helen, welcome to Stack Exchange.  You have posted this as an answer but it doesn't really answer the question.  It would be better to post this as a new question and link back to this question.